# Get the BackColor of inactive tab in TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, tabcontrol

I was wondering if there is a way to get the color of inactive tab in `TabControl`. The `TabPage.BackColor` property returns `SystemColors.Window` for both active and inactive tabs, which is the color of the active (selected) tab. However, the inactive tab should return something like `SystemColors.ButtonFace`.

[image: tabs]

The reason I'm asking is that I need no draw an image on a tab and before drawing a new one I try to erase the previous image.

Comment: My guess it is `SystemColors.Control`.

Comment: @Sinatr, I'd like to avoid having colors hard-coded in the source.

Comment: `SystemColors`, `SystemBrushes`, `SystemPens` are not hard-coded. Their values are updated to match current Windows theme. What I mean, is what there is no property to get or set color. But color is chosen based on the current theme. Though I couldn't find which one you have to set to change inactive tab-page header color. It could be, what it's hardcoded already in a way, what colors are predefined and you can't change them. It is more likely drawn by calling some helper (like `VisualStyleRenderer`). Could you draw image with `Transparent` Color? Or perhaps alpha channel will do a trick?

Comment: Maybe.. its a pure guess: *ControlName.DefaultBackColor;* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.defaultbackcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Sinatr, actually creating an icon with alpha channel and using `Graphics.DrawIcon` instead of `Graphics.DrawImage` did the trick. It eliminated the need to erase the previous image as the new image is just drawn over the old one. This method, however, will not work if the icon has intermediate transparency (like 50%).